# Using JavaScript setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I found out a lot of questions related to using of JavaScript setInterval() function and found the answers and also implemented them, but my hard luck, none could gain success. I might be doing some silly mistake, but i am not able to find it out now. Following is my code snippet.

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token",

data:`{"oauth_version":"1.0","oauth_signature_method":"PLAINTEXT","oauth_consumer_key":"consumer_key","oauth_signature":"signature&"}`,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'text', 
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    processData: true,
success: function(requestInfo)
{
        console.log("requestInfo: "+requestInfo);
    requestInfo = "http://localhost/?"+requestInfo;

    var oauth_request_token = processQueryStringData(requestInfo, 'oauth_token'); //a regex function that parses oauth_token from requestInfo
    var oauth_request_token_secret = processQueryStringData(requestInfo, 'oauth_token_secret');//a regex function that parses oauth_token_secret from requestInfo
    console.log("oauth_token_secret: "+oauth_request_token_secret);
    console.log("oauth_request_token: "+oauth_request_token);

    var url = "<url-to-redirect to dropbox alongwith callback url>";
    var win         =   window.open(url, 'DropBox Auth', 'width=800, height=600');  


var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
try {
        console.log("URL     ===== :   "  + win.document.URL);
        if(**some condition is true**)
        {
            window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
            // some code that i need to execute to get the authorize token and then the access tokens.
        }
    } 
catch(e)
{
}
}, 1000);

});
```

The ajax returns a success and i get the oauth_request_token and oauth_request_token_secret. Also dropbox log-in page opens in a child window. But the setInterval is not executed since i dont see the **console.log("URL     ===== :   "  + win.document.URL);** on the console.

Also, after reading a few answers, i created a function named **event** in which i placed the code from within the setInterval callback function and called that function like,

```
var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(event,1000);
```

At this time,**pollTimer** is global.Also, i saw the log statement only once and then the html page was refreshed. I am not able to understand where i am going wrong. Might happen to be a silly mistake, but not able to figure it out. Help please.

Note: This code lies in a function present inside a .js file which is included in a html file.

Comment: The "pollTimer" variable is not global if it's defined in your code as written. It's a local variable in that "success" callback. (That should be OK, as long as your "event" function is defined in that same function.)

Comment: Can you log `e` in your `catch` block? You may be hiding an error; depending on the value of `url`, for example, you may not be allowed to read `win.document.URL`. If an error is thrown there, `console.log` will never be called.

Comment: @Pointy - You are right that in the question above, "pollTimer" is not global, but when i created the "event" function i made the variable global.

Comment: @PaulRoub - i will try logging and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @PaulRoub, you are right. I logged the message and it says that "permission denied to access the property **document**". I will try searching why the error occurs. Let me know if you can help on it.

Comment: I'd start by reading up on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing. When you run function in setInterval, It is totally different context even if you call setInterval in ajax method. So I recommend to you to do check ****some condition is true**** statement first.

Comment: Sure. I will try doing it. Will let you know.

Comment: I was getting the permission denied exception. So as @PaulRob said, i will be reading the Same Origin Policy. Thanks for the help thou.